# Get one clojure project to "communicate" through a local server

Tags: clojure

I have a project which generates a puzzle and solves it in separate classes using the REPL. Is there any way to separate those classes into separate projects so that I can create a server that is on the same machine and can find puzzles already generated and return them to the calling client (puzzle solver) without the use of web servers?

Update: initially misunderstood what I was trying to do and reworded my question

Comment: You want to write (lein?) project as a library for two other projects (a cli and a web server).  Is this correct?  Otherwise you might have to elaborate on "communicte".

Comment: Oh yes after further thought it seems i misunderstood what i was trying to do, thanks. I've reworded the question.

Comment: I am still not sure, to what degree you want to communicate with a server.  So this might still not what you are looking for, but you could start a server repl or nrepl or whatever-revpl in one project and connect to it and then trigger commands there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you can. In broad strokes, you probably want:

- A single project with clear client, server and shared namespaces (eg. logic about solving puzzles that might be shared between client and server). There's nothing intrinsically wrong about bundling all the code together at first (later you can ship client+shared and server+shared separately)
- A library to make client/server communication simpler. A common use case is exposing the server with a web API because it's also simpler to test with web browsers, CLI clients (such as cURL), but it's OK if you want to use plain sockets and exchange messages in whatever format (EDN strings?) makes sense to you.

  - An example of a library for sockets would be https://github.com/atroche/clj-sockets , if you don't want to use Java interop and use classes from the `java.net` package directly.
  - Also note that web servers are actually socket servers too that listen for connections on fixed ports (eg. 80, 443 or 8080) for HTTP messages using certain conventions (eg. `GET /api/puzzles/1`)
- Finally, you'll need at least two namespaces that export a `-main` method: one to launch the server and another to launch a client.